# Why doesn't food taste good to my mouth?

Tags: side-effects, endocrinology, taste, weight-gain

Sorry I couldn't find a better title but by this question I'm not really looking for a cure. I'm just curious to know what happened to me and in my body.

So I would never enjoy food except a couple of dishes everything else used to taste terrible, maybe I should say I didn't like to eat. I would only eat to live and as soon as I feel I don't need it I would stop. Then I went to see a doctor and he was Endocrinologist. He prescribed me these medicines:

- Levothyroxine
- Nandrolone
- Cyproheptadine
- B complex
- oxymetholone
- Pancreatin
- Dexamethasone
- spironolactone (not in the first prescription)
- Hematinic

After a week or so the world was totally different. Anything I would eat, tasted awesome. I  would finish my dishes enjoyably. Even those dishes that I used to vomit by just looking at them was tasting incredible. Within 4 weeks i gained nearly 15 kilos (I was too skinny, only 48kg and 174 cm)

After 9 months or so the doctor reduced the dosage and I gradually stopped taking them. However 3 years later, I moved to Australia and again gradually I turned back to old days.

It's not as bad as old days but I again lost weight. I am always reluctant to have lunch and I push myself to eat. Even doing activities doesn't change my appetite really only a little that's not noticeable.

So my questions are:

1. What changes did those medicines make in my body that made things to taste different
2. Since I know the medicine are really dangerous to take and I don't want to take them again, is there anything equivalent to those pills, perhaps herbal, i can find with the same effect?

The first question is more important to me as I am very curious person about how things work. Thanks.

Please note I'm not looking for advice.

P.S. I didn't do any blood test or checkup of any sort and the specialist prescribed as per my comments.